# Accessing parent view from modal segue Swift

Tags: ios, swift, segue, parent-child

I have a View Controller - `NewsController` which has a modal segue going to `NewsDetailController`

In `NewsDetailController` I am trying to run the following function:

```
@IBAction func greenLikeClick(sender: AnyObject) {

    if let parentVC = self.parentViewController as? NewsController {
        parentVC.newslists[loadsection][loadrow].liked = false
    }
}
```

But this won't work.

Is there a parent-child relationship going on between `NewsController` and `NewsDetailController` here?

If so, why isn't my approach working?

If not, how would I approach this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should use `self.presentingViewController` in your `NewsDetailController`to get your `NewsController`. From the documentation:

> When you present a view controller modally (either explicitly or implicitly) using the presentViewController:animated:completion: method, the view controller that was presented has this property set to the view controller that presented it.

Comment: I replaced `self.parentViewController` with `self.presentingViewController` ... no luck unfortunately

Comment: Made a quick minimal example, this works. What is the type of your segue exactly ?

Comment: It is a `Present Modally` segue. Does this cause any issues? Sorry switched SO accounts, if you're confused. My bad.

Comment: No, it is fine, it is supposed to be a Present Modally Segue. At least, are you able to give your newsController a title and log it in your `NewsDetailController` ? with `presentingViewController.title?`

Comment: I figured out the problem. `presentingViewController` was giving me my Main Tab Controller, which contained `NewsController` as a child. So I said `let childOfTab = parentVC.childViewControllers[0] as! NewsController` and used this instead. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 1):

I did it like this for when my segue was pushed:

```
if let presenter = self.navigationController?.viewControllers[0] as? MainViewController {
        // access presenters members

}
```

and like this for when my segue was presented:

```
if let presenter = self.presentingViewController?.children[0] as? MainViewController  {
        // access presenters members
}
```

You should manage the children or viewcontrollers index if you have more than one. mine was single so 0 did the trick.